# UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION: Error:Execution failed for task ':dexDebug' in android studio

Tags: android, facebook

I have one problem.When I run my app,I got This error,But build successfully.I know that there are lib conflict error may be.I followed many URLs one of them is http://www.thedevline.com/search/label/Android%20development

But I did not get what is problem.Error is

Information:Gradle tasks [:assembleDebug]
:preBuild
:compileDebugNdk
:preDebugBuild
:checkDebugManifest
:preReleaseBuild
:facebook:compileLint
:facebook:copyReleaseLint UP-TO-DATE
:facebook:preBuild
:facebook:preReleaseBuild
:facebook:checkReleaseManifest
:facebook:preDebugBuild
:facebook:preDebugTestBuild
:facebook:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42103Library UP-TO-DATE
:facebook:prepareReleaseDependencies
:facebook:compileReleaseAidl UP-TO-DATE
:facebook:compileReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:facebook:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:facebook:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:facebook:mergeReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:facebook:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
:facebook:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:facebook:mergeReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:facebook:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
:facebook:processReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:facebook:generateReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
:facebook:compileReleaseJava UP-TO-DATE
:facebook:extractReleaseAnnotations UP-TO-DATE
:facebook:mergeReleaseProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
:facebook:processReleaseJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:facebook:packageReleaseJar UP-TO-DATE
:facebook:compileReleaseNdk UP-TO-DATE
:facebook:packageReleaseJniLibs UP-TO-DATE
:facebook:packageReleaseLocalJar UP-TO-DATE
:facebook:packageReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:facebook:packageReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:facebook:bundleRelease UP-TO-DATE
:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42103Library UP-TO-DATE
:prepareComFacebookAndroidFacebook3211Library UP-TO-DATE
:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServices6587Library UP-TO-DATE
:prepareDebugDependencies
:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:compileDebugJava
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
:preDexDebug
:dexDebug
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
Error:Execution failed for task ':dexDebug'.

> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
>       /home/manu-005/Android_Setups/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20140702/sdk/build-tools/android-4.4W/dx --dex --no-optimize --output /home/manu-005/workspace/AppName/build/intermediates/dex/debug /home/manu-005/workspace/AppName/build/intermediates/classes/debug /home/manu-005/workspace/AppName/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/support-annotations-21.0.3-49ca8e8cfc94918d7386df6065be15226206f457.jar /home/manu-005/workspace/AppName/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/bolts-android-1.1.4-61545c8defb142f83369be67bcebfa1f7690985c.jar /home/manu-005/workspace/AppName/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/MobileAppTracker-3.3.3-ca9457cd9ec6680ec9d845d2fc19efec4582c397.jar /home/manu-005/workspace/AppName/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/internal_impl-21.0.3-e77489df911cb5896aab6b91a4d4b9a838794c56.jar /home/manu-005/workspace/AppName/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/crittercism_v5_0_3_sdkonly-e644ef988027d1838362de88be35bbf0b876caf6.jar /home/manu-005/workspace/AppName/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/MobileAppTracker-javadoc-3.3.3-1641c6311e6f070ecd4d1320f44b1ba50b75dd0c.jar /home/manu-005/workspace/AppName/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/classes-001b548439aeb2e89d0d4f68cd7c4e4e33d1588c.jar /home/manu-005/workspace/AppName/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/android-support-v4-cc1887d592a4c530b10eb1125f7e630a900240bc.jar /home/manu-005/workspace/AppName/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/classes-34d67503c62f0f63b1f57f2f61a56c8d3b95a06e.jar /home/manu-005/workspace/AppName/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/classes-f79c881d5c91c7786b3cf2ab1a07ece9788351e8.jar
>     Error Code:
>       2
>     Output:
>       UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
>       com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/annotation/AnimRes;
>           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:594)
>           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:552)
>           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:533)
>           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:170)
>           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:188)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:439)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:287)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:230)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:199)
>           at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:103)
>   Information:BUILD FAILED
>   Information:Total time: 3 mins 39.856 secs
>   Information:1 error
>   Information:0 warnings
>   Information:See complete output in console

I tried many times but I am not able to resolve this error .Please help me.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please, explain the error. Just posting the stack trace is not enough. See: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

The issue is this:

> EXCEPTION: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define
>   Landroid/support/annotation/AnimRes; at

This occurs when you have multiple copies of the same class in your build, which means you have 2+ versions of the same android support library specified in your project.